# How can i call one of many php functions with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I have php website showing/hiding the pages through the nav links.
Im wondering how to call my php functions when clicking on the corresponding page link.
Is it possible to use ajax (jquery?) to call one of all the functions on my function.php file?
As i understand it ajax will run the whole code in the php file its calling?

```
$(document).on("click", ".dbLink", function() {
  var sText = $(this).attr("data-variable");
  $.ajax({
      url: '../ini/functions.php?q='+sText,
      type: 'get',
      success: function(data){
          alert(data);
      }
  });
});
```

function.php

```
function a(){
    echo "result";
}

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch($_POST['action']) {
       case "a":
          a();
          break;
       case "b":
          b();
          break;
       default:
          break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a string in the AJAX parameters, and have your PHP code run different functions depending on the string, e.g.

```
switch($_GET['op']) {
    case "delete":
        do_delete();
        break;
    case "update":
        do_update();
        break;
    ...
    default:
        // Report unrecognized operation
}
```

In your jQuery code, the handler function should call `event.preventDefault` or return `false` to prevent the normal action of the element you click on (I'm guessing it's a link). Also, you need to match the way you send the AJAX request with the way you retrieve the parameter in PHP -- if you use `$_POST`, you have to use `type: 'post'` -- and the parameter names must match (you used `q` in the Javascript, but `action` in the PHP).

```
$(document).on("click", ".dbLink", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sText = $(this).attr("data-variable");
    $.ajax({
        url: '../ini/functions.php',
        data: { action: sText }
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ahh. so the string should be passed in the ajax data attribute?

Comment: Well, in my example it should be in the URL parameter. You could pass it in the data, and then use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

Comment: if its with $_GET the ajax url attribute would for instance be: url: "functions.php?op=update"?

Comment: thanks, ill try. and a last question what would you recon is the smartest way to call my ajax with the html links? just something like $(document).on("click", ".link", function() { ajax }); ?

Comment: Something like that seems reasonable.

Comment: hope it would, ill be boxing too much around with this! thanks for all the inputs!

Comment: how can i change the variable im passing? like op=update above. i mean according to the link been clicked, i need to pass a variable for the switch in the php file

Comment: You can put `data-op="update"` in the `.link` element, use `$(this).data('op')` to get it, and then put that into the URL.

Comment: that was my solution. works fine, but the ajax call doesnt work for me. in my ajax i have: url: '../ini/functions.php?op='+stringVariable, type: 'GET', success: function(data){ alert(data) }

Comment: You need to post more code with context. Add it to the end of your question so you can post it with proper formatting.

Comment: i updated my code in the end of the question

Answer (score 1):

You can do ajax request to server with your data in request parameters.

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'your_functions_address.php',
dataType: 'json',
data: {functionname: 'add', arguments: [1, 2]},

success: function (obj, textstatus) {
              if( !('error' in obj) ) {
                  yourVariable = obj.result;
              }
              else {
                  console.log(obj.error);
              }
        }
});
```

and your_functions_address.php like this:

```
<?php
$aResult = array();

if( !isset($_POST['functionname']) ) { $aResult['error'] = 'No function name!'; }

if( !isset($_POST['arguments']) ) { $aResult['error'] = 'No function arguments!'; }

if( !isset($aResult['error']) ) {

    switch($_POST['functionname']) {
        case 'add':
           if( !is_array($_POST['arguments']) || (count($_POST['arguments']) < 2) ) {
               $aResult['error'] = 'Error in arguments!';
           }
           else {
               $aResult['result'] = add(floatval($_POST['arguments'][0]), floatval($_POST['arguments'][1]));
           }
           break;

        default:
           $aResult['error'] = 'Not found function '.$_POST['functionname'].'!';
           break;
    }

}

json_encode($aResult);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't call functions from AJAX. With AJAX you retrieve resources.

PHP is a resource preprocessor (as every server-side language is), so it executes code to bring you the so-called resource (html pages, css, images, ... are resources).

So, AJAX does not issue functions, since AJAX is not related to PHP but to HTTP requests.

In that sense, the AJAX-side could understand that it must issue a resource (and it DOESN'T KNOW that resource will trigger a chunk of server-side logic).

So, what you could expect to do is to send arguments (e.g. via GET or POST) and expect a result. In the other (i.e. the PHP) side you should consider those arguments and process them.

Perhaps sending parameters like functionName=func1&params=[1,2,%22a%22] and processing them like:

```
$func = $_GET['functionName'];
$params = json_decode($_GET['params']);

if (function_exists($func))
{
    $result = call_user_func_array($func, $params);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
else
{
    echo "unexistent function";
}
```

would do the job but, again, AJAX does not know about this, and never will, since AJAX is not related to PHP.

Comment: how would you send the functionName and params? what does the call_user_func_array do?

Comment: when you call the .ajax({}) with jQuery, send them as parameters in the data property, like: .ajax({method:"get", data:{functionName:"func1", params:JSON.stringify([1,2,"a"])}})

Comment: Perhaps you will need to include JSON.js file if your browser does not have a native JSON object